# Display highest value with its name

Tags: c++

I need a function that will go through below values and print out the highest value with its name. It is not hard to find the highest value which is 20 but I can't figure out a way to display the name of the value. Thank you!

Example:

```
North: 5
South: 10
West: 15
East :20
```

Output:

```
Winner is East with $20 in sales!
```

Here is what I got so far

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

double northeast, northwest, southeast, southwest;
// Function prototype
double getSales(string);
void findHighest();

int main()
{
    northeast = getSales("Northeast");
    northwest = getSales("Northwest");
    southeast = getSales("Southeast");
    southwest = getSales("Southwest");


    return 0;
}

//Function getSales
double getSales(string name)
{   cout << "What is the quarterly sales figure for " << name << "? ";
    double sales;
    cin >> sales;
    while (sales < 0)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a positive value ";
        cin >> sales;
    }
    return sales;
}

// Function getHighest
void getHighest()
{



}
```

Comment: Please show what you've got so far. The solution is probably a straightforward modification to your existing code.

Comment: How are the values stored?  A `map<string, currency>` ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Be clear.

Comment: This sounds like homework. If it is, please tag it as such.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thank you for your responses.  Following was the answer I was looking for.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

double NE, NW, SE, SW;
// Function prototype
double getSales(string);
void getHighest(double,double,double,double);

int main()
{
    NE = getSales("Northeast");
    NW = getSales("Northwest");
    SE = getSales("Southeast");
    SW = getSales("Southwest");

    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
    getHighest(NE, NW, SE, SW);

    return 0;
}

//Function getSales
double getSales(string name)
{   cout << "What is the quarterly sales figure for " << name << "? ";
    double sales;
    cin >> sales;
    while (sales < 0)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a positive value for " << name << " ";
        cin >> sales;
    }
    return sales;
}

// Function getHighest
void getHighest(double NE, double NW,
                 double SE, double SW)
{
    if (NE > SE && NE > NW && NE > SW)
        cout << "\nNortheast is the highest grossing division with $" << NE << endl;
    if (NW > NE && NW > SE && NW > SW)                      
        cout << "\nNorthwest is the highest grossing division with $" << NW << endl;
    if (SE > SW && SE > NW && SE > NE)                        
        cout << "\nSoutheast is the highest grossing division with $" << SE << endl;
    if (SW > SE && SW > NW && SW > NE)                        
        cout << "\nSouthwest is the highest grossing division with $" << SW << endl;

}
```

Comment: This is a poor solution. What happens if two regions both have the same highest sales? Also, what would you do if you had 100 regions?

Comment: You are right but this was an exercise in my book and we couldn't use struct or arrays since it wasn't covered yet.

Answer (score 2):

**use a struct to store string value and the double value.**
    **string will give the name and double the sales.**

```
struct sample
{
    string name;
    double sales;
};

void main()
{
    sample array[4];
    array[0].name = "NE";
    array[1].name = "NW";
    array[2].name = "SE";
    array[3].name = "SW";
    int i =0;
    while(i<4)
    {
       cout<<array[i].name;
       cin>>array[i].sales;
    }
    sample greatest;
    greatest.sales = array[0].sales;
    greatest.name = array[0].name;
    for(i = 0; i<4,i++)
    {
       if(ar[i+1].sales > array[i].sales)
       {
          greatest.sales = array[i+1].sales; 
          greatest.name = array[i+1].name;
       }
    }
    cout<<"greatest"<<greatest.name<<greatest.sales;
}
```

Comment: +1 for using struct which avoids using standard template library functions.

Comment: STL functions are better suited for advanced programs, for the basic and trivial ones struct is good enough. you can always modify the array to vetor and struct to map or multi map

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a map variable `map<string, double> b`

```
northeast = getSales("Northeast");
b.insert(pair<string,double>("Northeast",northeast));

northwest = getSales("Northwest");
b.insert(pair<string,double>("Northwest",northwest));
```

then add your getHighest method as follows:

```
void getHighest()
{
    map<string,double>::iterator i;
    string name;
    double value = b.begin()->second;

    for ( i = b.begin(); i != b.end(); i++ )
    {
        if ( value < i->second ) 
        {
            name = i->first;
            value = i->second;
        }
    }
    cout << name << " " << value << endl;
}
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: If you switch key and value of your map, the `getHighest` function is reduced to merely dereferencing `end()`.

Comment: @bitmask: Dereferencing `end()` is undefined behaviour, it should be `*--end()` or `*rbegin()`. :)

Comment: @Xeo: Yes, of course you're right -- must've been distracted. Nice catch :)